# Как сделать перемещение нод TreeView?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, drag-n-drop

Ветки нужно перемещать ноды на уровень выше в материнские и ниже в дочерние.

Моё дерево:

```
<TreeView x:Name="tw_tree"   
    dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True"
    dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True"

>
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate   ItemsSource="{Binding collection_node, 
    ConverterParameter=name_, Converter={StaticResource MySortConverter}}">
```

На другом примере работает нормально но в моём нет.

```
1
-2
--3
4
-5
--6
```

У меня любую ноду можно переместить в корень или в ту же ноду, в которой и находится. Например 3 можно переместить в корень либо в 2, где он уже есть.

В другие почему-то не перемещается.

```
public class Node
        {
            public string name_ { get; set; }


            public ObservableCollection<Node> collection_node { get; set; }

            public Node()
            {

                collection_node = new ObservableCollection<Node>();
            }
        }
```

Comment: это Windows.Forms. TreeView не содержит определения для ItemDrag

Comment: Сорри, не заметил метку, просто недавно с похожим вопросом разбирался. Нашел рабочий пример на WPF https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Drag-and-Drop-within-a-82d81c73/sourcecode?fileId=17223&pathId=1697201029

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Рекомендую использовать [GongSolutions.WPF.DragDrop](https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop), которую можно легко установить добавив соответствующий [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/gong-wpf-dragdrop/)-пакет.

Дальше к своему `TreeView`просто добавляете два свойства:

```
<TreeView 
          dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True"
          dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True" ... >
```

где `dd`:

```
xmlns:dd="clr-namespace:GongSolutions.Wpf.DragDrop;assembly=GongSolutions.Wpf.DragDrop"
```

Теперь вы можете легко перетаскивать элементы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у меня перетаскиваются ноды только на 1 уровень.

Comment: @codename0082016, не уверен, что правильно понял. У вас не работает перемещение между уровнями с помощью этого пакета или в проекте должна быть возможность перетаскивать только на один уровень?

Comment: перетаскиваются только в корневой уровень. На  уровни ниже (как на картинке) не перетаскиваются .

Comment: Обновлено. ещё что-нибудь добавить?

Comment: @codename0082016 т.к. я не могу воспроизвести проблему, мне нужен компилируемый пример, который я смогу запустить у себя и поискать причину неправильного поведения

Comment: @FoggyFinder, А не подскажите как запретить перетаскивание элемента определенного класса на элемент другого класса?

Comment: @FoggyFinder, У меня используется коллекция классов из этого вопроса: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/628801
При перетаскивании `ExpanderAction ` в `BaseAction` визуально все ок, но в `BaseAction` нет коллекции элементов и поэтому перетаскиваемый элемент просто исчезает. Хотя, повторюсь, в дереве все отображается нормально.

Comment: @maxwell полагаю, вам нужно обрабатывать `DropHandler`

Comment: @maxwell мы можем продолжить обсуждение в [SO чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26962/c-net--)? (я просто не всегда захожу на сайт и могу не заметить уведомление, а вкладку с чатами обычно держу открытой)