# Привязка внутри DataTemplate к самому себе

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть базовый класс `Action` обозначающий действие:

```
public class BaseAction
{
    public string Name  {get;set;}
}
```

И есть класс-наследник `ExpanderAction`, который обозначает череду таких действий:

```
public class ExpanderAction : BaseAction
{
    public List<BaseAction> Actions {get;set;} = new List<BaseAction>();
}
```

Также существует коллекция элементов, которая привязана к `ItemsControl`:

```
public ObservableCollection<BaseAction> Actions {get;set;} = new ObservableCollection<BaseAction>();
```

Элементы коллекции могут быть представлены 2 видами: 
кнопкой или другой коллекцией с элементами. Нужный шаблон выбирается через `ItemTemplateSelector`.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="BaseActionTemplate"  DataType="{x:Type actions:BaseAction}">
    <Button Content="{Binding Name}" />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="ExpanderActionTemplate" DataType="{x:Type actions:ExpanderAction}">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Actions}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Проблема в том, что внутри `ItemsControl`, который лежит в шаблоне `ExpanderActionTemplate` элементы нужно отобразить также 2-я теми же самыми шаблонами.
Получается что-то вроде рекурсии.

Подскажите, как указать внутри `ExpanderActionTemplate`, что данные в `ItemsControl` должны отображаться его же шаблоном?

---

**Update**

Делаю так, но возникает ошибка на строке `Second="{StaticResource Second}"`. Это происходит из-за того, что селектор объявлен раньше, чем шаблон данных `Second`.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="First">
        <Button Content="{Binding Name}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <local:Selector x:Key="Selector"
                    First="{StaticResource First}" 
                    Second="{StaticResource Second}"/>
    <DataTemplate  x:Key="Second">
        <ItemsControl ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource Selector}" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChildActions}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Actions}" 
    ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource Selector}"  />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Возможно, вам нужен по сути `HierarchicalDataTemplate`.

Comment: @VladD, Насколько я  понял `HierarchicalDataTemplate` можно нормально использовать только c `TreeView`. Если же использовать с `ItemsControl`, то дочерние элементы не отображаются.

Comment: А как вы подключаете `ItemTemplateSelector`? Приведите больше кода.

Comment: И что означает «теми же двумя шаблонами»? Почему нельзя внутри `ExpanderActionTemplate` в `ItemsControl` прописать тот же `ItemTemplateSelector`?

Comment: @VladD, Дополнил вопрос.

Comment: Написал ответ, пробуйте. Если так не пойдёт, есть и другие варианты.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У меня компилируется так:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="First">
        <Button Content="{Binding Name}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Second">
        <ItemsControl ItemTemplateSelector="{DynamicResource Selector}" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChildActions}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <local:Selector x:Key="Selector"
                First="{StaticResource First}" 
                Second="{StaticResource Second}"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

(хотя и с предупреждением).

---

Если вы не хотите использовать `DynamicResource`, можно обойтись и без него за счёт code-behind:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:Selector x:Key="Selector"/>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="First">
        <Button Content="{Binding Name}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Second">
        <ItemsControl ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource Selector}" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChildActions}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // обязательно после InitializeComponent
    var selector = (Selector)Resources["Selector"];
    selector.First = (DataTemplate)Resources["First"];
    selector.Second = (DataTemplate)Resources["Second"];
}
```

Comment: Работает, спасибо! А можете пояснить почему с `DynamicResource` все нормально в отличие от `StaticResource` и по каким причинам я могу не хотеть его использовать?

Comment: @maxwell: Ну, `StaticResource` подставляет ссылку на этапе компиляции, и требует, чтобы имя было определено в файле _до_ строчки, где он используется. А у вас из `Second` и `Selector` кто-то должен быть первым, и он не сможет сослаться на другого.

Comment: @maxwell: Я положил `DynamicResource` в `Second`, а не в `Selector`, поскольку `ItemTemplateSelector` является dependency property в нём, а что есть `Second` в `Selector`'е и как ведёт себя `DynamicResource` в случае не-dependency property, не знаю.

Comment: @maxwell: `DynamicResource` подставляется (в отличие от `StaticResource`) во время выполнения, поэтому ему всё равно, что и в каком порядке определено.

Comment: Понял, спасибо за разъяснения!

Comment: @maxwell: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло!

Answer (score 1):

Можно найти родительский `ItemsControl` и забрать у него свойство `ItemTemplateSelector`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ExpanderActionTemplate" DataType="{x:Type actions:ExpanderAction}">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Actions}" 
                  ItemTemplateSelector="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}, Path=ItemTemplateSelector}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```